# How to add CustomXmlResolver for signedXml Reference in dotnetCore 7

Tags: xml, .net-core

I am creating a signature using a certificate with private key to sign a XML request.

For that I am using `using System.Security.Cryptography.Xml`, the signature require three references, first reference with an uri to the keyInfo, second reference to the `SignedProperties` and the third reference should be null and here is my issue, I need to create a `CustomXmlResolver` for this last reference to use exactly the `<document:Document>` element from the request and calculate his `DigestValue`.

The two first references are fine, I have created a `CustomXmlResolver` and trying to tell him in case the is uri with null value to get the `<document:Document>` and return it to digest.

This is my code signature method:

```
public string createSignedSignature()
{
        const string signedPropsIdSuffix = "-signedprops";
        var key_cer = File.ReadAllText("private.key");
        var certPem = File.ReadAllText("certificate.cer");
        var idKeyInfo = "_" + Guid.NewGuid();
        var idKeyInfoProps = "_" + Guid.NewGuid() + signedPropsIdSuffix;
        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(certPem));
        // Load the XML document to be signed
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load("requestTemplate.xml");

        // Create a new XML digital signature
        SignedXmlWithId signedXml = new SignedXmlWithId(xmlDoc);
        RSA rsaKey = RSA.Create(); // Your RSA key here
        rsaKey.ImportFromPem(key_cer);

        // Load the RSA key into the XML digital signature
        signedXml.SigningKey = rsaKey;

        #region Keyinfo
        //Adding the key info
        var keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
        KeyInfoX509Data keyInfoData = new KeyInfoX509Data();
        keyInfoData.AddIssuerSerial(cert.Issuer, cert.SerialNumber);
        keyInfo.AddClause(keyInfoData);
        signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
        keyInfo.Id = idKeyInfo; 
        #endregion Keyinfo

        // Add a reference to the signed data
        //First Reference
        Reference reference = new Reference();
        reference.Uri = $"#{keyInfo.Id}" ; //"#_69e11b4e-4a1b-4b29-8524-dca818ffcc1a"; // Reference URI
        reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
        reference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";
        //reference.DigestValue = ComputeDigestValue(xmlDoc.InnerXml.ToString());
        signedXml.AddReference(reference);

        //Properties
        XmlElement qualifyingPropertiesElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xades", "QualifyingProperties", "http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#");
        XmlElement signedPropertiesElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xades", "SignedProperties", "http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#");
        signedPropertiesElement.SetAttribute("Id", idKeyInfoProps);
        XmlElement signedSignaturePropertiesElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xades", "SignedSignatureProperties", "http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#");
        XmlElement signingTimeElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xades", "SigningTime", "http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#");
        signingTimeElement.InnerText = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz");
        signedSignaturePropertiesElement.AppendChild(signingTimeElement);
        signedPropertiesElement.AppendChild(signedSignaturePropertiesElement);
        qualifyingPropertiesElement.AppendChild(signedPropertiesElement);

        XmlElement objectElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ds", "Object", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");
        objectElement.AppendChild(qualifyingPropertiesElement);

        //second reference
        Reference reference_1 = new Reference();
        reference_1.Uri = $"#{idKeyInfoProps}"; //"#_be79647c-c233-47f8-8624-7ea025185d3f-signedprops"; // Reference URI
        reference_1.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
        reference_1.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";
        //reference_1.DigestValue = ComputeDigestValue(xmlDoc.InnerXml.ToString());
        signedXml.AddReference(reference_1);
        //Third reference
        //XElement docelement = xmlDoc;

        Reference reference_2 = new Reference();
        reference_2.Uri = "Bonour"; //"#_be79647c-c233-47f8-8624-7ea025185d3f-signedprops"; // Reference URI
        reference_2.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
        reference_2.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";
        //reference_1.DigestValue = ComputeDigestValue(xmlDoc.InnerXml.ToString());
        CustomXmlResolver resolver = new CustomXmlResolver(xmlDoc);
        signedXml.AddReference(reference_2);

        // Add the ds:Object tag with xades:QualifyingProperties element
        // Save the signed XML document

        //xmlDoc.Save("requestTemplate.xml");
        signedXml.ComputeSignature();
        
        Console.WriteLine(signedXml.GetXml().OuterXml);
        return xmlDoc.ToString();
    }
```

And this my CustomXmlResolver :

```
public class CustomXmlResolver : XmlResolver
{
    private readonly XmlDocument _xmlDoc;

    public CustomXmlResolver(XmlDocument xmlDoc)
    {
        _xmlDoc = xmlDoc;
    }

    public override object? GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, string? role, Type? ofObjectToReturn)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(absoluteUri.ToString());

        if (absoluteUri == null)
        {
            // If URI is null, target the <document:Document> from xmlDoc
            XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(_xmlDoc.NameTable);
            nsManager.AddNamespace("document", "documentNamespace"); // Add appropriate namespace
            XmlNode documentNode = _xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//document:Document", nsManager);

            if (documentNode != null)
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
                sw.Write(documentNode.OuterXml);
                sw.Flush();
                ms.Position = 0;
                return ms;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to find the Document element in xmlDoc.");
            }
        }

        return base.GetEntityAsync(absoluteUri, role, ofObjectToReturn);

        //else
        //{
        //  // Default behavior for resolving other URIs
        //  throw new NotImplementedException("CustomXmlResolver does not support resolving external URIs.");
        //}
    }

    public override Uri ResolveUri(Uri baseUri, string relativeUri)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(baseUri);
        return base.ResolveUri(baseUri, relativeUri);
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Type of input object is invalid. (Parameter 'obj')

and this from the StackTrace:

> at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.XmlDsigExcC14NTransform.LoadInput(Object obj)
> at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.TransformChain.TransformToOctetStream(Object inputObject, XmlResolver resolver, String baseUri)
> at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.Reference.CalculateHashValue(XmlDocument document, CanonicalXmlNodeList refList)
> at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.Reference.UpdateHashValue(XmlDocument document, CanonicalXmlNodeList refList)
> at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.BuildDigestedReferences()
> at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.ComputeSignature()

Please can someone help me?

The issue is on this reference2

```
    Reference reference_2 = new Reference();
    reference_2.Uri = "Bonour"; //"#_be79647c-c233-47f8-8624-7ea025185d3f-signedprops"; // Reference URI
    reference_2.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
    reference_2.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";
    //reference_1.DigestValue = ComputeDigestValue(xmlDoc.InnerXml.ToString());
    CustomXmlResolver resolver = new CustomXmlResolver(xmlDoc);
    signedXml.AddReference(reference_2);
```

Thank you for helping.